# Django tag better way to resolve string with variable

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I have a tag that has a variable that is a string with an embeded variable.  Is there a better way to evaluate it than:

```
{% custom_extends  "this_{{is.a.test}}" %}
```

-- backend

```
string_with_variable = "this_{{is.a.test}}"
result = Template(string_with_variable).render(context)
```

This works, but i wasn't sure if there was any lower level function that does the same.

Comment: I've generally seen people suggest using dictionaries for variables with variable names/values. Not sure if that would work here, but might be a possibility.

Comment: Yea I have some that do kwargs, but in this case its generally one parameter.  The issue is I am just trying to render the string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.  As of right now if you want to resolve/render a string  you need to instantiate a `Template` and call render with your context.

```
result = Template("this_{{is.a.test}}").render(context)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'm a little dense this morning. Is the problem getting `some_custom` to accept a param that has an embedded variable reference in it? Or is it that you want the param to `some_custom` to be resolved before it is passed (which is a more general situation)?

If it's the latter case, checkout the [Expr templatetag](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/9/). With that you can do something like:

```
{% expr "this_"+is.a.test as some_string %}
{% some_custom some_string param %}
```

**Update for comment:**

Since this is for `{% extends %}`, which, as you correctly point out, needs to be the very first line in the file, simply set a variable in your view, e.g. `my_custom_template = "this_"+is.a.test+".html"` and pass it in with the context. Then in your template you can say `{% custom_extends my_custom_template %}` and you're good to go.

Of course, this assumes that your `custom_extends` tag does variable resolution like the normal `extends` tag does, but that's an easy thing to add to your code. See `django/template/loader_tags.py`, `ExtendsNode.get_parent()` for how the core code does it.

Comment: I am looking for a simpler way to render "nick {{my_var}}" in the custom template .  Right now I basically create a template and render it... figured there has to be some method that can eval a string.

Comment: The `expr` template tag is what you want. The Django team decided (unwisely, IMNSHO) to create a deliberately limited template language. Not only is it weak in terms of flow control, it's "new" variable syntax sucks. Supposedly this made it easier for "template designers" because they didn't have to be programmers, but all of the templates I've ever seen were first done by designers in Photoshop, and then implemented in Django by ... programmers.

Comment: I need a server side solution to this, my tag has to be the first in the template.  So i am looking for a better way,than the way I did it above,in python to be able to evaluate a string with embedded vars.

Comment: When I first started looking into this I saw that extends can resolve variables and chose not to use that route because i did not want to couple my controllers to my views.  Aka I did not want to hardcode a path in my controller to my template.  I would rather have the template depend on the controller.